# How to embed Tawk chat to OpenCart 3

Tags: javascript, opencart, opencart-3, tawk.to

I am using OpenCart release 3.0.2.0, I don't know where to embed Javascript code

```
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5997bc0d1b1bed47c/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
</script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
```

Point out for me, where to put Tawk code to OpenCart 3. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in `catalog/view/theme/your-theme-name/template/common/footer.twig` before `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to embed Javascript code**

- Login as Admin for OpenCart 3.0.2.0
- Go to Design
- Theme Editor
- Select your theme ie., Default from drop down menu
- Select common from Choose Template
- Then footer.twig

Now, you can add the Javascript code where you want.